# Jquery datatable

Tags: 2010, filter, jquery-ui

[image]

I have a custom list with Employee Name, Approval Status, Created Date columns in it.I am using SharePoint 2010 version.
I want to display the list items depending on one of the column "Approval Status" when equals to Approved in a page.
In page I have a set up of text box , date filter and a button as shown in figure

when i type in the employee name and select the dates and click on the filter button it should get the results based on the column value of approval status equals approved below.I am trying to implement this using jquery can someone help me in this scenario. thanks

Comment: Please tag SharePoint version. Why can't you use list view webpart? You can use that to easily filter based on Query String or Connected Filter (Html Part) web part.

Comment: Updated the version , SharePoint 2010 . Amal could you provide me any links or idea of how to follow in doing it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel I believe.

From your requirement we can easily achieve using `HTML Form` webpart. And then connect it to a `List View` webpart for filtering.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-HTML-Form-Web-Part-to-filter-and-display-data-in-another-Web-Part-860b681c-38ad-43ff-a036-a60868497ff7

The good thing about this approach is you will get all features of list view (sorting, filtering, add new fields easily etc.)

Comment: But this won't help my scenario I am looking to have something like nothing should be displayed by default and once i enter employee name  in the text box  and date in the date filter and click on button as shown in figure it should show the the respective results below depending on approval status is equals to approved.

Comment: You can put empty space in the employee name field on page load and I believe that will return nothing.

Comment: you mean I should write something up in html ,,,sorry if i meant something wrong technically as am not a pro in developing.thanks

Comment: Yes update the html and add space character as the text in employee name textbox